# SDWebImage Cancel download

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

I am using SDWebimage to load images on my tablkeview
I am following [this](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html) tutorial

Now I stuck on a problem,If I scroll down and hit back before images get loaded the app got crashes.How can I solve this ?

How to cancel the SDWebImage download.
I have gone through some answers and discussions.But none of them helped me and could not use them

Please help me

I am using

```
  [cell.UserImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[SDWebArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: U solve it? Or ....

Answer (score 14):

In your cell, you can cancel the image load if it's going to get re-used. In your `UITableViewCell` subclass add the following:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [self.imageView cancelCurrentImageLoad]; // UIImageView for whatever image you need to cancel the loading for
}
```

Be sure to `#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"` as well.

Though your app shouldn't be crashing, but I cannot help you without seeing some code, since it's not possible to pinpoint the cause of the crash from your description above.

Comment: I updated the question and add some code,as I said I am using this tutorial...http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.com/2013/04/lazy-image-loading.html

Comment: The code I provided above should solve it, did you try it? I think your crash is related to something different. What is the crash description?

Answer (score 3):

**SWIFT 4.0**

```
self.imageView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
```

In case you are using SDWebImage Activity Indicator and wants to remove that as well

```
self.imageView.sd_removeActivityIndicator()
```

Comment: `sd_removeActivityIndicator()` was removed in SDWebImage 5.0. Instead, you can use `self.imageView.sd_imageIndicator?.stopAnimatingIndicator()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)cancelAll
{
    for (SDWebImageDownloader *downloader in downloaders) {
    [downloader cancel];
    }
    [cacheDelegates removeAllObjects];
    [cacheURLs removeAllObjects];

    [downloadInfo removeAllObjects];
    [downloadDelegates removeAllObjects];
    [downloaders removeAllObjects];
    [downloaderForURL removeAllObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line of code when your `SDWebImage` is already loaded:

```
[self.imageView cancelCurrentImageLoad];
```